# How to log in to AWS cognito user pool using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to log in the user to the AWS Cognito user pool using PHP SDK. I am following this tutorial, https://sanderknape.com/2017/02/getting-started-with-aws-cognito/. But I am getting the error.

Here is my code:

```
$credentials = array(
            'key' => env('AWS_IAM_KEY', ''),
            'secret' => env('AWS_IAM_SECRET', '')
        );

        //2014-06-30
        $client = CognitoIdentityClient::factory(array('region' => env('AWS_REGION',''), 'version' => 'latest', $credentials));

        $result = $client->adminInitiateAuth([
            'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
            'ClientId' => COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
            'UserPoolId' => COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
            'AuthParameters' => [
                'USERNAME' => "name",
                'PASSWORD' => 'password',
            ],
        ]);

        $accessToken = $result->get('AuthenticationResult')['AccessToken'];
```

When I run the code, I got this error:

```
 InvalidArgumentException
Operation not found: AdminInitiateAuth
```

It is saying the AdminInitiiateAuth does not exist. But I am correctly following the tutorial. What is missing in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that [CognitoIdentityClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentity.CognitoIdentityClient.html) does not contain the adminInitiateAuth functionality.

You will need to use the [CognitoIdentityProviderClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentityProvider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient.html)

Comment: But in all the tutorials, they using CognitoIdentityClient and call the method in it. Is there a tutorial for logging in using CognitoIdentityProviderClient? All I found was using the CognitoIdentityClient.

Comment: Think the main problem here is that the tutorials you are following are a bit outdated. AWS splitted up the functionality between CognitoIdentityClient  and CognitoIdentityProviderClient quite some time ago. The only example I could find is here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248662

Comment: As I can see, your tutorial is using CognitoIdentityProviderClient

Comment: I yeah. I solved the error. Thanks so mucccchhhhhhhhhhhh. Everything done.

Comment: Did you just change the client to ```CognitoIdentityProviderClient``` and it worked? I am doing that but it did not work for me. Also is the value of ```'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',``` something different or could be that?